# Cleanest way to forward internet traffic to private load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I'm currently trying to connect my users originating from the internet to a service running in an isolated VPC (let's call it `VPC_s` for "service"). To do so, I set up a Transit Gateway between `VPC_s` and a VPC (and associated subnets) that contains an Internet Gateway (let's call it `VPC_i`).

Knowing that I have a DNS entry for an internal network load balancer in `VPC_s` and the underlying service entry points:

- How can I cleanly allow my users to access the service in `VPC_s`? What should I put in `VPC_i` to forward traffic to the DNS of the private load balancer?

Thanks!

Comment: "Knowing that I have a DNS entry service.acme.com that resolves to the IP of an internal network load balancer" that internal IP will only work within the private VPC network. You can resolve it externally, but that private IP address will then point to something in each user's private network, not to your load balancer. You have to have a public IP for the DNS resolution to work for users on the Internet.

Comment: Hey @MarkB, I made my question a bit clearer, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An internal load balancer by definition exists on a private subnet, so any DNS entry that points to it will not be routable to the public. Cloudfront also requires that origins be internet-accessible so you can't front it that way. You could either set up some sort of reverse proxy on a public subnet, or set up a public ELB pointing to the private. There is also a [gateway load balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/gateway-load-balancer/) that does the same sort of thing, but isn't quite for this use case, costs the same when you factor in the required VPC endpoint, and offers less interoperability with common services.

If it were me in this scenario, I'd have CloudFront front a public ELB in a public subnet attached to the transit gateway, and a traffic subnet that's private. The traffic subnet routes and logs and filters when appropriate. The traffic subnet would route the requests to the private subnet where your internal load balancer resides, and reflexive routes allow the outbound traffic to go back to the originating public ELB. Users connect to CloudFront only. This way, if I need to rearchitect something later, I can do it in a way that's transparent to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the input! That's kinda the setup I have at the moment. Just by curiosity, how would you "set up a public ELB pointing to the private one" when AWS load balancers don't support ELB/NLB/ALB chaining? Or am I wrong maybe?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can do this, just make the target group of the public load balancer the private IP of the internal. Then set up your routing so it can be reached. Several ELB options offer static IPs now.